# Image is not set in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a two activities where I use camera in one activity and another activity just has a imageview to display the picture that i took using camera. I am able to view the picture successfully in first activity where I took the picture and I want to send the image (or) image path to next activity to display the image and add some effects but I am unable to do that.

**CODE :**(UPDATE)

**Sending Activity :**

```
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);
                    view_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
                    System.out.println(path);
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    int count = 0;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
                    ++defaultValue;
                    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key", defaultValue).commit();
                    count = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key", count);
                    System.out.println("The value if count is " + count);
                    image_name_2 = "Image " + count;
                    File file = new File(path,image_name_2 + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        Intent image_intent = new Intent(Snap_ImageView.this,FullScreen.class);
                        Log.i("SnapImageView",image_name_2);
                        image_intent.putExtra("image_path" ,image_name_2 );
                        Log.i("SnapImageView","Extra has been passed");
                        System.out.println("The image name is " + image_name_2);
                        startActivity(image_intent);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();

                    }
```

**Receiving Activity :**

```
String path = android.os.Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
    System.out.println("Reached FullScreen");
    location = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_path");
    System.out.println("Got the extra" + location);
    File image_file = new File(path + File.separator + location);
    String fil_value = image_file.toString();
    System.out.println("The full image name is " + fil_value);
    {

    OutputStream outfile = null;
    outfile = new FileOutputStream(image_file);
    Log.i("Inside try block","At OutputStream");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(location);
    Log.i("Inside try block","Decoding is over");
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85,outfile);
    Log.i("Inside try block","File is compressed");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**Logcat :**

```
12-31 12:24:38.662: I/dalvikvm-heap(9245): Grow heap (frag case) to 25.995MB for 24023056-byte allocation
12-31 12:24:39.203: D/dalvikvm(9245): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 3% free 26515K/27299K, paused 23ms
12-31 12:24:39.253: I/System.out(9245): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/SanPics2
12-31 12:24:39.403: I/System.out(9245): The value if count is 24
12-31 12:24:40.814: I/SnapImageView(9245): Image 24
12-31 12:24:40.814: I/SnapImageView(9245): Extra has been passed
12-31 12:24:40.814: I/System.out(9245): The image name is Image 24
12-31 12:24:41.145: D/memalloc(9245): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51e83000 size:28549120 offset:26460160 fd:58
12-31 12:24:41.435: I/System.out(9245): Reached FullScreen
12-31 12:24:41.435: I/System.out(9245): Got the extraImage 24
12-31 12:24:41.435: I/System.out(9245): The full image name is /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/SanPics2/Image 24
12-31 12:24:41.435: I/Inside try block(9245): At OutputStream
12-31 12:24:41.435: I/Inside try block(9245): Decoding is over
12-31 12:24:41.465: D/AndroidRuntime(9245): Shutting down VM
12-31 12:24:41.465: W/dalvikvm(9245): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab1228)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.facebook_integration/com.example.facebook_integration.FullScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at com.example.facebook_integration.FullScreen.onCreate(FullScreen.java:64)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
12-31 12:24:41.515: E/AndroidRuntime(9245):     ... 11 more
```

Logcat shows that the image is not set but it has done with decoding and **compressing** is where it gets the **error**. The image is stored with the specified date name and it is stored at exact specified location.

If I comment the compress line then I am getting a plain white background in ImageView.

If someone sees anything weird with the code, then please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Any updates, feel free to ask.

Comment: Pls check your imagepath twice I think imagepath is wrong

Comment: Thanks Kailash. Thats exactly where I had gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where's the extension of the picture. you need to specify extension as well.

Comment: Should I use the image name also in the  string path or just the path where the image is stored ? If I need the image name as well, the problem is that I am generating the image name dynamically according to date and time so any suggestions on how to add that to image path ? Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: you need to specify the name in the path. but you are generating name as date and time so you have to keep track of names set.otherwise how will get to know that which picture you want to set and you can't use random as well for selecting name of picture.

Comment: you can also store the name of the last image in a variable and then pass it to the next activity which then combine it with the path and retrieve the image.

Comment: I will update the post as you've suggested. Just take a look at it and tell me if that will work.

Comment: Thanks pal. It kinda worked but threw me an OutOfMemory Exception thereby not setting the image. Great work.

Comment: try this : <br> bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, file);

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Will try it and let ya know.

Comment: Can I pass file as null ? If yes, then it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: No , file is the image which you are going to compress otherwise i think it raise exception

Comment: Nah, OutOfMemeory again. Please check my updates, I have edited it as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: nah, you are doing wrong. get time as name in variable like image and then use it as a name for your image and then pass this name to next activity and then get this image name from intent and then use it to read image from sd card. time is changing continuosly so in next activity you will get some different name thats why you are not getting .

Comment: put name in intent.putextra and then retrieve it.

Comment: It has worked when I checked for existence of file content, no error now but the same fact remains. The image is not being set,it shows a plain white background.

Comment: Tried that too but still the image view doesn't set the image. Thanks for your suggestions, helped me a lot.

Comment: try to log your bitmap by converting it to string and check whether it contain something or is it empty.

Comment: I have found that the error lies in compressing the image. Not sure what is causing it !!

Comment: If I comment the compress line then it shows a empty white image again.

Comment: try to put some appropriate compress ratio. i.e try to change value of 40 in the above compress statement and run again.

Comment: Tried that too. Used 85 but the issue remains !!

Comment: reduce parameter value. do not increase it.

Comment: read this. it might help :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29

Comment: The only method there which is used to compress is the one that I use !!! Anyways, thanks for all your effort pal.

Comment: I just found out that while passing the image name from one activity to another, the second activity gets only the name of the previously stored photo and not the current one that I am requesting !! How's it possible ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set bitmap on to Imageview like below:

```
    File imgFile = new File(
            "yourpath/" + file_name(Specific file name with extension));
    //System.out.println("Image Exists:::" + imgFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        // System.gc();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                .getAbsolutePath());
        //System.out.println("Image Exists:::");

         imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
```

You should check first image is exist into your specify location and if exist then decode the image and set to imageview and is not then display some error message.

Comment: Thanks M D. But still the issue persists. Done some updates though, please check it out if possible.

Comment: First of all check that your Images are create successfully into your specified folder with your specified Name.

Answer (score 1):

I know this will be a lot of reading but this will surely solve your problem. [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs only when the imagepath is wrong.You should check your imagepath.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially found out the answer that makes the image set in image view from the path. But I have not achieved the compress thing in bitmap. I have removed the bitmap compress line in the below code.

**CODE :**

```
  String path = android.os.Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator
                    + "Pictures" + File.separator + "SanPics2";
            System.out.println("Reached FullScreen");
            location = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_path");
            System.out.println("Got the extra" + location);
            File image_file = new File(path + File.separator + location);
            String fil_value = image_file.toString() + ".jpg"; // Add the image extension along with the image name.
            System.out.println("The full image name is " + fil_value);

            Log.i("Inside try block","At OutputStream");
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fil_value); // I had passed the location variable which has the image name but not with its extension and then I added the fil_value which has the image name along with the extension
                String bit = bmp.toString();
                Log.i("Bitmap is",bit);
                Log.i("Inside try block","Decoding is over");
                Log.i("Inside try block","File is compressed");
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Do not forget to add the **extension of the file name and its accurate path**. Double check if the image exists in the your specified location. I thank all the users who had answered these question for helping me out to figure the issue.